# What's required to properly escape a URI for use in HttpClient.PostAsync?

Tags: c#, http

Most overloads of `HttpClient.PostAsync()` allow either a string or `URI` to be passed in. Some however (in the `Formatting` namespace) only allow a string. To use this, I build and use a URI string like:

```
string uri = "http://myserver.com/" + userSuppliedName + "/dosomething/";
client.PostAsync(uri, someObject, formatter);
```

My concern now is that `userSuppliedName` can be something invalid or malicious, so I want to make sure it is escaped properly.  In the documentation for `System.Uri`, it states that by default a passed in string will be escaped properly, but since the `PostAsync` method I'm using only supports a string URI, I want to check: will it escape properly automatically? If not, should I just be escaping `userSuppliedName` when constructing `string uri` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Uri.EscapeDataString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string uri = "http://myserver.com/" + Uri.EscapeDataString(userSuppliedName) + "/dosomething/";
client.PostAsync(uri, someObject, formatter);
```

Comment: This seems like the better solution, but doesn't really answer whether this method escapes the URI automatically or not! If you happen to know/find out, please edit in case someone comes along with question :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `new Uri(uri).AbsoluteUri` as the first parameter and alleviate encoding issues. It'll do it for you.